# Design A Database and Relationship Diagram and Views

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

A Company has the Following Departments. They need to build a letter management system. That means, some persons, companies and government agencies send letters to them. They need to collect those letters information to a system and manage. This is a project for my study. I need help to build the DB, ER Diagram, Reports and other needs. Help me.

Divisions
1.  Admin Division      -
a.  First, postman handover all the letters to the admin branch. 
b.  Admin branch marks the important details of each letter in a book such as Client Name, Address, Tp Nos, Fax Nos, Emails, Subject of the letter, Letter Type (Personnel Letter, Official, or Other), Received Date, Action required (like Today, Immediate or Normal), My No (if has on letter) etc
c.  Deliver the letters for responsible branch/person of each branch and branch head / responsible person sign a delivery book when received. Delivery book has following data – Who send, Who to, Send Date, Accepted date (Branch head/Responsible person), Forward Method (First time, Re forward – because when some letter delivered to wrong branch, they return to the letter again Admin branch. These routings should be recorded. 
d.  If received letter is official, puts the date stamp on the letter. Letters categorized according to the subject and keep them on suitable file. Each file has a file no. and each letter on a file has page no for each letter.  Each branch manage records like letter received date, Date on Letter (Clients written Date), Action Taken (Send the reply), Page No of Replied letter, 
e.  That is the idea and need to get reports when letters are received, what are the actions have taken by the branches.

2. Account Division
3. Dept Head Division
4. HR Division
5. IT Division

I need to build a database for above purpose. Pl help me and can any body design the database, Relationship diagram, reports, and views and any other comment needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use workbench to design your database:
*https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/*
First you have to find out what all the primary keys are. After that you just build the table how you want it. After that start thinking how the tables are related to eachother.